# Rails: Search & Filter Books by Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I need some help please. I am building an **advanced search feature** for my digital library, and I would like to search books by their names or description and then by also filter the search results by the category which the books belongs.

The database is structured this way: **Books belongs sub-categories and categories, while sub-categories belongs to the categories only. But I want to filter by categories.**

Let's say I have a book named **Great Achievers** and **Great Developers** and they belong to the categories **Achievers** and **Developers** respectively. I want the search to work this way: when I search using the keyword **Great** I would see the books **Great Achievers** and **Great Developers**, and when I filter by category **Achievers** I would see only **Great Achievers**.

Right now my advanced search feature can search for books by their names and descriptions, but cannot filter the books by category in the search results.

**This is the code for the book model**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :upload
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  belongs_to :sub_category, required: false

  def self.search(keywords)
      if keywords
        where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR author LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%").order('id DESC')
      else
        order('id DESC') 
      end
    end
end
```

**This is the code for the category model**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_categories
  has_many :books
end
```

**This is the code for the sub-category model**

```
class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :category, required: false
 end
```

**This is the truncated code for the books controller**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.search(params[:keywords]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  private
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :description, :category_id, :sub_category_id, :new_sub_category_name, :upload, :keywords, :deep_keywords)
    end
end
```

**This is the truncated code for the search feature on the books index view**

```
<%= form_tag(books_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %>
    <%= collection_select :category, :id, Category.all.order('name ASC'), :id, :name,{include_blank: 'Select Category'} %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

**I have attached a screenshot of my console log when a search action is done**[image]

**Please any form of assistance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is to find the books that are under filter category. Then filter from that books collection based on the search term.

**You can modify the books controller code as below.**

```
def index 
if params['category'].blank? or params['category']['id'].blank? 
@books = Book.all 
else 
category = Category.find(params['category']['id']) 
@books = category.books 
end 
@books = @books.search(params[:keywords]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order('created_at DESC') 
end
```

**The truncated code for the search feature on the books index view can remain the same**

```
<%= form_tag(books_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %>
    <%= collection_select :category, :id, Category.all.order('name ASC'), :id, :name,{include_blank: 'Select Category'} %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

**The code for the book model can also remain the same**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :upload
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  belongs_to :sub_category, required: false

  def self.search(keywords)
      if keywords
        where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR author LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%").order('id DESC')
      else
        order('id DESC') 
      end
    end
end
```

I hope this helps.

**Upvote this answer as useful if it helps, or comment below the answer for more clarification.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do I have to make any changes to my **book model** and my **book index** view search feature to enable to work properly?

Comment: @PromisePreston, No need to change anything in book model file. Just update the Index method i have answered in books controller. This should work fine. Please verify.

Comment: Hi @dharmesh and @CAmador, I just tried out this answer but I get this error.

**NoMethodError in BooksController#index**. 
'undefined method `search' for #<Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000559a0d3ae628> Did you mean? each'. How do I go about it?

Comment: @PromisePreston, Just tested your example in my sample app. No need to change anything in book model. The search function should remain as the same in the question.

Just update the Book controller and try this answer and accept the answer if it works fine.

Comment: Hi @dharmesh, I just tried it now  and it worked, but the search results doesn't filter  by category yet. It simply displays the search for books based on their names, description and author without filtering the books results when I select a particular category during the search. Can you help out please. Thanks.

Comment: @PromisePreston Can you please let me know the parameters value that is logged in rails server log/console when making the call?

Comment: @dharmesh, I just attached a console log screenshot to the question

Comment: @PromisePreston, Updated the if condition in the answer. This would work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191739/discussion-between-dharmesh-and-promise-preston).

Comment: @dharmesh, I am still facing some issues with the category filtering. 
Thank you so much for your help, I will continue this discussion in chat.

Answer (score 1):

Searching is something that you can avoid doing on your own if you use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). You can even do a one-liner in your controller with it to achieve what you want:

```
def index
    @books = Book.all.ransack(params[:q]).results.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
end
```

[Then in your requests you have to pass the](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#in-your-view) `params[:q]`, doing whatever search you need done for the books resource. I.E:

```
#params[:q] for books with category_id == 10
{ "category_id_eq": 10 }
#params[:q] for books with name or description or author matching "search"
{ "name_or_description_or_author_matches": "%search%" }
#params[:q] for books with name or description or author matching "search" and category_id == 10
{ "name_or_description_or_author_matches": "%search%", "category_id_eq": 10 }
#params[:q] for books with name or description or author matching "search" and category_id == 10, ordered by created_at
{ "name_or_description_or_author_matches": "%search%", "category_id_eq": 10, "s": "created_at desc" }
```

Check the [available matchers](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching) so you can build your filters as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You need a join (untested, but you get the idea):

```rb
def self.search(params)
  books = where(nil)
  keywords = params.dig(:keywords)
  if keywords
    books = books.where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR author LIKE ?",
                         "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%")   
  end

  cat_id = params.dig(:category, :id)
  if cat_id
    books = books.joins(:category).where(category: {id: cat_id})
  end

  books.order('id DESC')
end
```

EDIT:

```rb
  def index
    @books = Book.search(params).
             paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9).
             order('created_at DESC') # You already set order on search
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do I have to make any changes to my **books controller** and my **book index** view search feature to enable to work properly?

Comment: Hi @CAmador, I just tried it, here's the error that I ran into: **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Books#index**

SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: name: SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "books"."category_id" WHERE (name LIKE '%nursing%' OR description LIKE '%nursing%' OR author LIKE '%nursing%') AND "category"."id" = ? ORDER BY id DESC, created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?. How do I solve it?